# Keeping my metabolism high

Tags: food, supplements, metabolism

I am looking for some diatary ways to keep my metabolism high, especially between meals.

What kinds of foods or supliments can help keep your body processing long after you've consumed them?

Ideally I'm looking for categories *not* a list of examples

Comment: this doesn't exactly answer your question because it isn't related to food/nutrition but... Increase Type II muscle mass. More muscles means an increased basal metabolic rate meaning you burn more energy doing nothing and even more when you exercise. It's also the easiest way to keep it off in the long term.

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to answer your question in the way that you requested, "in categories *not* a list of examples".

### Metabolism Boosters

- Spicy Foods - Jalapeno, Habanero, and Cayenne Peppers.
- Protein Meat - Lean Beef, Pork, Chicken, and Turkey.
- Protein, Dairy - Milk, Yogurt.
- Protein, Fish - Salmon, Tuna, and Sardines.
- Protein, Eggs - Chicken eggs.
- Caffeinated Beverages - Green Tea and Coffee.
- Whole Grains - Brown Rice, Oatmeal, and Quinoa.
- Dark Leafy Greens - Spinach, Bok Choy, and Broccoli.
- Low-sugar Fruits - Apples, Pears, Berries, Oranges, Kiwis, and Peaches.  (organic preferred)

**Resources/Links**

[Fifteen foods that fire up your metabolism](http://www.sanbenito.k12.tx.us/hot%20news/fifteen_foods.html)

[15 fat-burning foods](http://www.nydailynews.com/lifestyle/health/toplists/15_fatburning_foods/15_fatburning_foods.html)

[4 food groups that can boost your metabolism](http://www.wellness-junction.com/health-wellness/4-food-groups-that-can-boost-your-metabolism/)

[Foods that Speed Metabolism](http://www.myfit.ca/foods_that_speed_metabolism.asp)

Comment: Good answer (but eggs arent dairy!)

Comment: Moved eggs into their own category :)

Answer (score 4):

Drink lots and lots of water, this will keep the system running smoothly.

You can put this in the *fluids* category if you need one.

Answer (score 1):

Green Tea is thing to have lots of.

It contains a great deal of Catechin's that has a metabolic enhancing effects. Additionally, Green tea contains a lot of excellent anti-oxidants.